# require core wordpress php files

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress

I am using angular on a wordpress site to generate animated page transitions. The angular HTML code is generated by PHP in a wordpress custom template, and I have set angular up to fetch individual php files.

When the php files are fetched by angular, basic php code is executed fine. However, anything wordpress related is not found. I am guessing because the wordpress php files have been executed already on the initial page load.

I used require in the php files and gave the paths to some of the files I was using, but they still need the wordpress php files to function so they throw a `500 (Internal Server Error)`

```
<div id="pageone">
    <p>This is page 1.</p>
    <a href="#page2">Go to page 2 </a><br>

    <?php

echo ('this php line works');

require './../../lib/custom.php';
echo ('this file is found, but needs wordpress functions, so throws 500 error');

    ?>
</div>
```

I think I can use require to fetch the core wordpress php files but I don't know which php file that is..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the core php file for wordpress (for roots theme anyway) is located in

> web/wp/wp-load.php

```
require './../../../../../wp/wp-load.php';
```

blurb from wp-load

```
/**
 * Bootstrap file for setting the ABSPATH constant
 * and loading the wp-config.php file. The wp-config.php
 * file will then load the wp-settings.php file, which
 * will then set up the WordPress environment.
 *
 * If the wp-config.php file is not found then an error
 * will be displayed asking the visitor to set up the
 * wp-config.php file.
 *
 * Will also search for wp-config.php in WordPress' parent
 * directory to allow the WordPress directory to remain
 * untouched.
 *
 * @internal This file must be parsable by PHP4.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
```

Comment: And in a normal WP install, it's simply in the WP root folder.

Comment: I suspect you're [loading WP two times](http://crappycode.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/wp-load-php-i-will-find-you/). If it's a custom template, there should be an entry point to avoid that.

Comment: The code you shown is not enough... How's it related to your custom template?